# redux-form is refreshing the page onSubmit

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I have a redux form that when submitted, is causing the entire browser page to refresh which is not desired...

What am I doing wrong here to cause the page to refresh on submit?

**Rate.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import RateForm from '../../components/rate/RateForm';

class Rate extends React.Component {

  handleSubmit(data) {
    alert('x')
    console.log('handleSubmit');
    console.log(data);
  }

  render() {

    const fields = [
          {
            name: 'execution',
            type: 'select',
            options: [
              { label: '5', value: '5' },
            ],
          },
        ]

    return (
      <div>
        <RateForm fields={fields} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} />

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Rate;
```

**RateForm.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

const renderField = ({ input, field }) => {
  const { type, placeholder } = field
  if (type === 'text' || type === 'email' || type === 'number' || type === 'checkbox') {
    return <input {...input} placeholder={placeholder} type={type} />
  } else if (type === 'select') {
    const { options } = field
    return (
      <div>
        <label>{field.name}</label>
        <select name={field.name} onChange={input.onChange}>
          {options.map((option, index) => {
            return <option key={index} value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
          })}
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return <div>Type not supported.</div>
  }
}

class RateForm extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
        {this.props.fields.map(field => (
          <div key={field.name}>
            <Field
              name={field.name}
              component={renderField}
              field={field}
              />
          </div>
        ))}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    )
  }

}

RateForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'rateForm'
})(RateForm);


export default RateForm;
```

Comment: Pass the prop to RateForm by handleSubmit by name as OnSubmit `<RateForm fields={fields} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} />`

Comment: Thank you! that worked. Why not leave an answer and get the credit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `handleSubmit` function as handler to the `RateForm` component by the reference name `onSubmit`.

Use this

```
 <RateForm fields={fields} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} />
```

Answer (score 2):

inside `render` method:

```
render(){
    const { handleSubmit, ... } = this.props;
    return(
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.yourSubmitFunction)}></form>
    );
}
```