# Refreshing issue when submitting form with react-redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-redux-form

### Issue

**Important:** This has been solved; see below explanation.

I've been having this issue of the page refreshing when submitting a react-redux-form. I have found a lot of similar issues since this is the default behavior of submitting a form in HTML; however I haven't found anything related to this specific library (react-redux-form).

I've also tried to apply what was suggested in other cases, mainly the event.preventDefault(), but I don't know how to use the event object with this library as they recommend the following syntax:

```
<LocalForm onSubmit={(values) => this.handleSubmit(values)}>
```

I've tried with values.event, but that was unsuccessful.

Below what I intend to have:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Hall from './HallComponent';
import { Row, Button, Label } from 'reactstrap';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import { LocalForm, Control } from 'react-redux-form';

class Endgame extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      redirect: false
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(values) {
    const date = new Date();
    this.props.addScore({
      date: date.toLocaleDateString("en-GB"),
      name: values.name,
      score: this.props.points
    });
    this.setState({ redirect: true });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
      return (
        <Redirect to="/hall" />
      );
    }
    else {
      return(
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
              <p>Your score is: {this.props.points}</p>
              <p>Add you name to the Hall of Fame</p>
              <LocalForm onSubmit={(values) => this.handleSubmit(values)}>
                <Row className="form-group">
                  <Label htmlFor="name">Nickname</Label>
                  <Control.text model=".name" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" className="form-control"  />
                </Row>
                <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
              </LocalForm>
            </div>
            <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
              <Hall scores={this.props.scores} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    }

}

export default Endgame;
```

### Solution

I've found that the problem was not coming from the submit button but the way I had arranged my components.
I'm still not entirely sure of what actually happens behind the scene, but my Hall component above was unmounted and re-mounted each time the addScore() e.g. a redux action was fired. I found out that this could happen if the state of the parent component was modified somehow this could trigger re-mounting of children components.
I've migrated the state locally to Hall component connecting it to redux store and it now works properly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like your question might be a duplicate. Perhaps you could look at it and see if it helps, and if not explain what's different?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redux-form is refreshing the page onSubmit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44486190/redux-form-is-refreshing-the-page-onsubmit)

Comment: Thanks :)
it's not the same library (redux-form vs react-redux-form).

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. Maybe delete your "redux-form" tag to make this more clear?

Answer (score 0):

its because you have a button of type "submit". Its default action is to refresh the page.

```
                <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
```

You can put an `evt.preventDefault()` in your handle submit function to stop the page from refreshing, but I would encourage you to just change the button type and put your handleSubmit function on the onClick event like this.

```
                <Button type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks Chase.
How do I get access to the form's values (previously as parameters in handleSubmit)?

Comment: Unfortunately if you use onClick and not a submit button you will need to have these form values set in state or redux so you can access them on state in the function. If you don't feel like writing that out just use evt.preventDefault().

Comment: You need access to the event object in your function so change how you put handleSubmit in LocalForm to this onSubmit = (values, evt) => {this.handleSubmit(values, evt)}

Comment: Chase - I've tried your last comment with (values, evt) but the page keep refreshing.

With regards to your first comment, my point of using the library was to avoid managing the data.
I've also found that it is supposed to already perfom event.preventDefault() as described in the docs: https://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/docs/api/Form.html